# Default context for AlertDialog.Builder for map view?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) on using Google Map View in Android. In the second part, they create an `mContext` member variable and then pass that into `AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)`, but the constructor that they call to create an instance of an `HelloItemizedOverlay` doesn't instantiate `mContext`, so it's just left `null` as far as I know.

The program doesn't work properly, and throws a `NullPointerException` as I suspected. How is this supposed to work?

Thanks,
Jengerer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial, step 2 (the onCreate section) they instantiate a HelloItemizedOverlay:

```
HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
```

But notice that in the HelloItemizedOverlay constructor, it takes a Drawable and Context:

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(defaultMarker);
    mContext = context;
}
```

So the fault is with the tutorial. They're instantiating the class without a Context object, making it null. In your onCreate() method, just add `this` to the constructor.

Comment: Right, I tried this and it didn't work, but I realized that they also left out the line that initialized the `ArrayList`, which is why it was crashing even with this fix. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I was just focusing on the Context issue, didn't even notice that. Glad I could partially help!

Answer (score 0):

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

Answer (score 0):

Create a single constructor for `HelloItemizedOverlay` accepting two parameters: `drawable` and `this`.

The tutorial sounds like you need to make two constructors for different number of parameters.